# Tight legend border with no title

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to make the border around a legend tighter when the legend has no title. As it is, there is a blank space above the legend key. I'd also like the border to be a dotted line.

[image: ggplot2]

The plot is based on the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(temp, aes(x=diff_abs, y=emp_est_15, color=diff_sign)) + geom_point(shape=1, size=2) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("green4", "red")) +
  scale_x_log10(breaks=10^(0:3)) + scale_y_log10(breaks=c(c(2,4,8) %o% 10^(0:3))) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        axis.text = element_text(color="black", size=13), axis.title = element_text(color="black", size=13),
        legend.key = element_blank(), legend.position=c(.2,.8), legend.box.background = element_rect(), 
        legend.background = element_blank()) +
  labs(x="\nGain ou perte d'emploi 2001-2015 (milliers, échelle log 10)", 
       y="Emploi 2015 (milliers, échelle log 10)\n", color="")
```

Comment: ?`theme(legend.title = element_blank())`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Richard Telford mentioned in the comment, setting `legend.title = element_blank()` will remove the space occupied by legend title & hence "tighten" the legend box.

Legend box's border type can be changed with `legend.box.background = element_rect(line = <some number other than 1>)`

```
# example using mtcars dataset
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, col = factor(cyl)))
p + geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        legend.key = element_blank(), legend.position=c(.8,.8), 
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.box.background = element_rect(line = 3), 
        legend.background = element_blank())
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A small addendum to [Z. Lin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8449629/z-lin) answer; one can get rid of the remaining blank space on the top by setting `legend.spacing.y = unit( 0, 'pt' )`

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, col = factor(cyl))) + geom_point() +
  theme_bw( base_size = 80 ) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        legend.key = element_blank(), legend.position=c( 0.5, 0.5 ), 
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.box.background = element_rect(line = 3), 
        legend.background = element_blank() )
lgndA <- cowplot::get_legend( p )
lgndB <- cowplot::get_legend( p + theme( legend.spacing.y = unit( 0, 'pt' ) ) )
grid::grid.newpage()
cowplot::plot_grid( lgndA, lgndB )
```

[Legends with different legend.spacing.y option in ggplot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiWte.png)